# Ошибка доступа для чтения

Tags: c++, ms-word, макрос

Основная проблема в том что при передаче файла .doc 97/2003, спустя несколько итераций, переменная 'ls' становится больше 0x10 вызывая прерывание выполнения и ошибку доступа.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "ole2.h"
#include <iostream>

#define MAXBUF 0xFFFF
#define NAMELEN 256
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
char Buf[MAXBUF];  // поток
char SBuf[MAXBUF]; // распакованный текст
using namespace std;
ULONG search_chunk(char* Buf, ULONG streamlen)
{
    ULONG ch_pos; // Позиция чунка внутри потока

    if ((Buf[0] == 1) && (Buf[1] == 0x16) && (Buf[2] == 1))
    {
        ch_pos = streamlen / 2;
        while ((ch_pos < (streamlen - 3)) && ((Buf[ch_pos] != 1) ||
            ((Buf[ch_pos + 2] & 0xF0) != 0xB0))) ch_pos++;
        if (ch_pos < (streamlen - 3)) return ch_pos;
    }
    return 0;
}
    typedef UINT(WINAPI* RTLD)(ULONG, PVOID, ULONG, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);сюда код
void view_src(char* StreamName, char* Buf, ULONG ch_pos){
    HMODULE h;                // Хэндл библиотеки NTDLL.DLL
    RTLD RtlDecompressBuffer; // Указатель на функцию
    ULONG ulen;               // Длина распакованного фрагмента
    int i;
    LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
    h = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
    RtlDecompressBuffer = (RTLD)GetProcAddress(h, "RtlDecompressBuffer");
    if (RtlDecompressBuffer)
    {
        RtlDecompressBuffer(0x2, SBuf, MAXBUF, &(Buf[ch_pos + 1]), MAXBUF - ch_pos, &ulen);
        cout << "-------------------" << StreamName << "-------------------" << endl;
        i = 0; while (SBuf[i]) cout << SBuf[i++];
    }
}
    // Рекурсивный обход дерева потоков.
void walk(const char* s, LPSTORAGE ls){
    OLECHAR FileName[NAMELEN];  // Unicode-имя для structured storage
    char StreamName[NAMELEN];   // ASCII-имя потока
    LPENUMSTATSTG lpEnum = NULL;    // Интерфейс перечислителя
    LPSTORAGE pIStorage = NULL; // Интерфейс структурированного хранилища
    LPSTORAGE pIStorage2 = NULL;    // Интерфейс хранилища нижнего уровня
    LPSTREAM pIStream = NULL;   // Интерфейс потока
    STATSTG stat;       // Очередная запись в каталоге
    ULONG uCount;       // Счетчик перечисления
    ULONG streamlen;        // Реальная длина потока
    ULONG ch_pos;       // Позиция чунка внутри потока
    if (!ls) // Первый вызов
    {
        mbstowcs(FileName, s, 256);
        StgOpenStorage(FileName, NULL, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, NULL, 0, &
            pIStorage);
        walk("", pIStorage);
    }
    else // Повторный рекурсивный вызов
    {
        ls->EnumElements(0, NULL, 0, &lpEnum);
        if (lpEnum)
            while (lpEnum->Next(1, &stat, &uCount) == S_OK)
            {
                if (stat.type == STGTY_STORAGE) // Это хранилище
                {
                    ls->OpenStorage(stat.pwcsName, NULL, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
                        NULL, 0, &pIStorage2);
                    walk("", pIStorage2);
                }
                else // поток
                {
                    ls->OpenStream(stat.pwcsName, NULL, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, 0,
                        &pIStream);
                    pIStream->Read(Buf, MAXBUF, &streamlen);
                    wcstombs(StreamName, stat.pwcsName, 256);
                    ch_pos = search_chunk(Buf, streamlen); 
                    if (ch_pos) view_src(StreamName, Buf, ch_pos);
                }
            };
        ls->Release();
    }
   }
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) walk(argv[1], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Основная проблема в том что при передаче файла .doc 97/2003, спустя несколько итераций, переменная 'ls' становится больше 0x10 вызывая прерывание выполнения.

Comment: Вы бы это в вопрос записали, а не в комментарий.